# Use Join to display tracklist's tracks

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a `tracklists` table containing the *id*, *name* and *description* of tracklists and a `tracks` table containing the *id*, *name* and *tracklist_id* of tracks.

Now lets say that I want to display a HTML table where each rows presents a tracklists, something like this:

[image]

I want to do this in a single database request (using PDO) but I have a hard time figuring:

- How to make a join request to get the tracklists infos **and** the tracks for each one of them;
- How to treat the result (with a `foreach` for example) to create a (HTML) table row for each album while including the related list of tracks.

---

At first, I tried not to use a *join* request and to simply make a function that would output the list of tracks, like this:

```
function listTracks($id) {
  $pdo = dbConnect();

  $request = "SELECT * FROM tracks AS track WHERE album_id = :id";
  $stmt = $pdo->prepare($request);
  $variables = array('id' => $id);

  $result = $stmt->execute($variables);
  $tracks = $stmt->fetchAll();

  $trackList = "";

  foreach ($tracks as $track) {
    $trackList .= "<li>" . $track["name"] . "</li>";
  }

  return $trackList;

}
```

I noticed that it was way to slow to make a new database request to get the tracks of each tracklists, which is why I tried the join solution with a request like this:

```
$request = "SELECT tracks.name, tracklists.*
            FROM tracklists
            INNER JOIN tracks
            ON  tracklists.id = tracks.album_id";
```

Problem being that this request returns an array and I don't understand how I'm supposed to display it the way I want to (I always end up making a table row for each tracks instead of each tracklists).

Comment: Nobody will write this for you .... you need to show an attempt to solve it yourself. Suggest you break this down to separate questions and show what you tried for both

Comment: @charlietfl I'll edit my post to show what I tried, thank you for your insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL Query to fetch all albums and track list
    function listTracks() {
    $sql = "SELECT tkl.id, tkl.name, description, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT tk.name SEPARATOR '
') trackslist 
    FROM tracklists tkl LEFT OUTER JOIN tracks tk 
    ON tk.tracklist_id=tkl.id GROUP BY tkl.id ORDER BY tkl.id DESC";

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$list = "";

foreach($result as $tracks => $track){
$list .= "<li>".$track['name']."</li>
<li>".$track['description']."</li>
<li>". $track['tracklist'] ."</li>";
}
return $list;
}
```

If you want to supply album id to the query use

```
function listTracks($id) {
$sql = "SELECT tkl.id, tkl.name, description, 
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT tk.name SEPARATOR '<br />') trackslist 
FROM tracklists tkl LEFT OUTER JOIN tracks tk 
ON tk.tracklist_id=tkl.id WHERE tk.id=:id GROUP BY tkl.id ORDER BY tkl.id DESC";
$param = array(':id' => $id);

$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute($param);
$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$list = "";

foreach($result as $tracks => $track){
$list .= "<li>".$track['name']."</li>
<li>".$track['description']."</li>
<li>". $track['tracklist'] ."</li>";
}

return $list;
}
```